# Node.js Module not found

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am experience a Module Not Found error for an NPM package that is installed and appears to be present in the node_modules folder.  Is something missing in the underlying package itself?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cmtest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "cmtest",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "Andrew"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cloudmersive": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

And then I am calling a require:

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var Cloudmersive = require('cloudmersive');
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');



    var api = new Cloudmersive.BarcodeLookupApi()

    var value = "value_example"; // {String} Barcode value


    var callback = function (error, data, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            console.log('API called successfully. Returned data: ' + data);
        }
    };
    api.barcodeLookupEanLookup(value, callback);
}).listen(port);
```

But I am getting this error:

```
"Cannot find module 'cloudmersive'"
"Error: Cannot find module 'cloudmersive'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\cmtest\cmtest\server.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:675:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)"
```

Any ideas?  Is there something wrong with the package itself?  Is it a development/configuration issue on my part?

The package cloudmersive is installed with NPM and shows up in the node_modules folder.  I also tried using nvm to switch between several different versions.

Underlying package source is here: https://github.com/Cloudmersive/Cloudmersive.APIClient.Javascript

Is there something wrong with the index.js file?

Comment: read their read me for Installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`package.json` for cloudmersive says main is `src/client.invoker/index.js` but the file is not in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

To use the library locally without publishing to a remote npm registry, first install the dependencies by changing
into the directory containing `package.json`. Let’s call this `JAVASCRIPT_CLIENT_DIR`. Then run:

`npm install`

Next, link it globally in `npm` with the following, also from `JAVASCRIPT_CLIENT_DIR`:

npm link
Finally, switch to the directory you want to use your cloudmersive from, and run:

`npm link /path/to/<JAVASCRIPT_CLIENT_DIR>`

You should now be able to `require('cloudmersive')` in javascript files from the directory you ran the last
command above from.

You can checkout the `README.md` file inside the `cloudmersive` module which you have installed inside your `node_modules` directory to get more detailed instructions on this.